# How to find the next element in the tree

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, tree, console-application

I have a tree like below:

```
/* Tree 
*            5 
*         /    \ 
*        3      1 
*       / \    / \ 
*      2   4  6   7 
*/
```

I am creating this tree using a class called Node as below:

```
var root = new Node(
            5,
            new Node(
                3,
                new Node(2),
                new Node(4)),
            new Node(
                1,
                new Node(6),
                new Node(7)));
```

I wanted as a result to print out the ordered tree: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.
I am able to find the next larger element referring to this example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-larger-element-n-ary-tree/ , but I can't find out how to print the all nodes in order.

Edited:

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = new Node(
        5,
        new Node(
            3,
            new Node(2),
            new Node(4)),
        new Node(
            1,
            new Node(6),
            new Node(7)));

        var n = root;

        while (n != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n.Data);
            n = n.NextNode();
        }
    }

    public static Node NextNode(this Node node)
    {
        var newNode = NextLargerElement(node, node.Data);

        return newNode;
    }

    public static Node res;
    public static Node NextLargerElementUtil(Node root, int x) 
    {
        if (root == null)
            return null;

        if (root.Data > x)
            if ((res == null || (res).Data > root.Data))
                res = root;

        foreach (var children in root.Children)
        {
            NextLargerElementUtil(children, x);
        }

        return res;
    }

    static Node NextLargerElement(Node root, int x)
    {
        res = null;

        NextLargerElementUtil(root, x);

        return res;
    }
}
```

And the `Node` class:

```
public class Node
{
    private List<Node> _children;

    public Node(int data, params Node[] nodes)
    {
        Data = data;
        AddRange(nodes);
    }

    public Node Parent { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Node> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children != null
              ? _children
              : Enumerable.Empty<Node>();
        }
    }

    public int Data { get; private set; }

    public void Add(Node node)
    {
        //Debug.Assert(node.Parent == null);

        if (_children == null)
        {
            _children = new List<Node>();
        }

        _children.Add(node);
        node.Parent = this;
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<Node> nodes)
    {
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            Add(node);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Data.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use binary search tree, that the left child is smaller then parent that smaller then the right child

Comment: Please, share your code for search

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I've just edited the question, you can see the code above

Comment: Also the `Node` class.

Comment: @JQSOFT Above you can find the `Node` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [recursive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/recursive-functions?view=vs-2019) / [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) function to iterate over all the branches and get all the nodes:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Node> GetAllNodes(Node parent)               
{
    IEnumerable<Node> GetAllNodes(IEnumerable<Node> children)
    {
        foreach(var child in children)
        {
            yield return child;
            foreach(var c in GetAllNodes(child.Children))
                yield return c;
        }
    }

    yield return parent;

    foreach(var child in GetAllNodes(parent.Children))
        yield return child;
}
```

If you have a tree like:

```cs
var root = new Node(5,
    new Node(3, new Node(11), new Node(12),
    new Node(2),
    new Node(4), new Node(13)),
    new Node(1, new Node(14), new Node(15),
    new Node(6, new Node(16), new Node(17)),
    new Node(7, new Node(8), new Node(9))), new Node(10));
```

Call the function, pass the `root` node, and OrderBy the `Data` property:

```cs
var q = GetAllNodes(root).OrderBy(x => x.Data).Select(x => x.Data);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", q));
```

The output is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
```

Preferably, make it an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the `Node` type.

```cs
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Node> GetAllNodes(this Node parent)
    {
        IEnumerable<Node> GetAllNodes(IEnumerable<Node> children)
        {
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                yield return child;
                foreach (var c in GetAllNodes(child.Children))
                    yield return c;
            }
        }

        yield return parent;

        foreach (var child in GetAllNodes(parent.Children))
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

So you can call it as follows:

```cs
var q = root.GetAllNodes().OrderBy(x => x.Data).Select(x => x.Data);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", q));
```